# Transporting a bulky instrument case on a bike

Tags: commuter, cargo

I've been considering trying out riding to school on my bike. Only problem is that I play French Horn in band, which would makes the logistics of it difficult. Is there a way that I could strap it down to my rack on the back of my bike?

Comment: this may also answer your question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/75571/how-to-carry-a-trumpet-for-long-trips

Comment: Specific to your horn - I see there are products like https://houghtonhorns.com/shop/protec-case-backpack-straps/  intended to convert a soft-case into a backpack.  Depending on what case you have now, you might be able to rig straps.  Your other school books and stuff may be best in a pannier bag.

Comment: @kevin Please don't be discouraged by the closure of this question - it is quite a good question, so much that it has been asked before and there are pre-existing relevant answers.    Another option that may be relevant to you is to store the horn at school, perhaps the music department has a lockup ?

Comment: IMHO the safest way is a Danish cargo bike, also called bakfiets in the NL